# Grepping and sedding IP from ip addr show

Tags: sed, arch-linux, grep, ip

I'm trying to get just the local IP of my Arch VM. I've managed to get just the line containing what I want with grep, but I also want to trim it down with sed.

```
inet <<192.168.0.16>>/24 brd 192.1680.255 scope global enp0s3 $ I want the IP in <<>>
ip addr show | grep 'inet\ ' | sed -n -e 's/^.*inet\ (.*)\/.*$/\1/p'
-n     # print nothing by default
s      # replacement command
^      # begin line
.*     # anything
inet\  # inet and then a space
(.*)   # capture anything
\/     # end capture at the / that comes before 24
.*     # anything
$      # end
\1     # replace all that with the first capture group which should be the IP
p      # print the output
```

But as soon as I add the sed, it gives me nothing. I assume something is wrong with my regex.

Comment: @don_crissti Oh right! Thanks, I forgot about that. That actually fixes my problem. Sorry for the bad information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easier to do with `awk` than `grep` and `sed`:

```
ip addr show eth0 | awk '/inet / {print $2}'
```

If you want to strip the CIDR netmask from the IP:

```
ip addr show eth0 | awk '/inet / {gsub(/\/.*/,"",$2); print $2}'
```

Note that an interface may have more than one IP address - e.g. `ip addr show br0 | awk '/inet / {print $2}'` on my system has 11 IPv4 addresses, some of them being public IP addresses and some of them RFC1918 private addresses.